# jstl condition show different tables based on url

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jsp, jstl

For each owner in a database, I need the users of a web application to be able to click on different buttons to load different information.  For example, the code below is a jsp in which users select an owner at left, which loads detail information for the selected owner sel_owner at right.  Then there are three buttons for the sel_owner, one to show cats owned by sel_owner, another to show dogs owned by sel_owner, and a third to show all pets owned by sel_owner.  The instrumental code involves the url patterns in the three buttons, and the three c:if tags, each surrounding a different dandelion datatable, which should either be visible or invisible, depending on which button is clicked by the user.

How do I set this up to work in my spring mvc hibernate maven application in eclipse?  At the moment, the .endsWith("cats") or dogs or all clause is triggering an error message in eclipse saying that endsWith() is not a supported method for String.  How do I fix this so that it works as intended?

Here is the code for the jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="datatables" uri="http://github.com/dandelion/datatables" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="joda" uri="http://www.joda.org/joda/time/tags" %>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>PetClinic :: a Spring Framework demonstration</title>

    <spring:url value="/webjars/bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" var="bootstrapCss"/>
    <link href="${bootstrapCss}" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <spring:url value="/resources/css/petclinic.css" var="petclinicCss"/>
    <link href="${petclinicCss}" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <spring:url value="/webjars/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.js" var="jQuery"/>
    <script src="${jQuery}"></script>

    <!-- jquery-ui.js file is really big so we only load what we need instead of loading everything -->
    <spring:url value="/webjars/jquery-ui/1.10.3/ui/jquery.ui.core.js" var="jQueryUiCore"/>
    <script src="${jQueryUiCore}"></script>

    <spring:url value="/webjars/jquery-ui/1.10.3/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" var="jQueryUiDatePicker"/>
    <script src="${jQueryUiDatePicker}"></script>

    <!-- jquery-ui.css file is not that big so we can afford to load it -->
    <spring:url value="/webjars/jquery-ui/1.10.3/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" var="jQueryUiCss"/>
    <link href="${jQueryUiCss}" rel="stylesheet"></link>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td width=160 valign="top">
            <datatables:table id="owners" data="${selections}" cdn="true" row="owner" theme="bootstrap2" 
                      cssClass="table table-striped" paginate="false" info="false" 
                      cssStyle="width: 150px;" align="left" >
                <datatables:column title="Name" cssStyle="width: 150px;" display="html">
                    <spring:url value="/owners?ownerID={ownerId}" var="ownerUrl">
                        <spring:param name="ownerId" value="${owner.id}"/>
                    </spring:url>
                    <a href="${fn:escapeXml(ownerUrl)}"><c:out value="${owner.firstName} ${owner.lastName}"/></a>
                </datatables:column>
            </datatables:table>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <h3>Owner:</h3>
            <table class="table table-striped" style="width:600px;">
                <tr>
                    <td><b><c:out value="${sel_owner.firstName} ${sel_owner.lastName}"/></b></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${sel_owner.address}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${sel_owner.city}"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${sel_owner.telephone}"/></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=2> 
                        <spring:url value="/owners?ownerID={ownerId}&type=cats" var="owner_catsUrl">
                            <spring:param name="ownerId" value="${sel_owner.id}"/>
                        </spring:url>
                        <a href="${fn:escapeXml(owner_catsUrl)}" class="btn btn-info" >Show Cats</a>

                        <spring:url value="/owners?ownerID={ownerId}&type=dogs" var="owner_dogsUrl">
                            <spring:param name="ownerId" value="${sel_owner.id}"/>
                        </spring:url>
                        <a href="${fn:escapeXml(owner_dogsUrl)}" class="btn btn-info" >Show Dogs</a>

                        <spring:url value="/owners?ownerID={ownerId}&type=all" var="owner_allUrl">
                            <spring:param name="ownerId" value="${sel_owner.id}"/>
                        </spring:url>
                        <a href="${fn:escapeXml(owner_allUrl)}" class="btn btn-info" >Show All Pets</a>
                     </td>
                </tr>

                <c:if test="${pageContext.request.requestURI.endsWith('all')}">
                <tr>
                <td colspan=2>

                    <p>Pets</p>
                        <datatables:table id="pets" data="${sel_owner.pets}" cdn="true" row="pet" theme="bootstrap2" 
                                  cssClass="table table-striped" paginate="false" info="false"  filter="false"
                                  cssStyle="width: 350px;" align="left" >
                            <datatables:column title="Name" cssStyle="width: 200px;" display="html">
                                <c:out value="${pet.name}"/>
                            </datatables:column>
                            <datatables:column title="BirthDate" cssStyle="width: 300px;" display="html">
                                <joda:format value="${pet.birthDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                            </datatables:column>
                            <datatables:column title="Type" cssStyle="width: 200px;" display="html">
                                <c:out value="${pet.type.name}"/>
                            </datatables:column>
                        </datatables:table>
                </td>
                </tr>
               </c:if>
                <c:if test="${pageContext.request.requestURI.endsWith('cats')}">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=2>
                        <p>Cats</p>
                        <datatables:table id="cats" data="${sel_owner.cats}" cdn="true" row="cat" theme="bootstrap2" 
                                  cssClass="table table-striped" paginate="false" info="false"  filter="false"
                                  cssStyle="width: 350px;" align="left" >
                            <datatables:column title="Name" cssStyle="width: 200px;" display="html">
                                <c:out value="${cat.name}"/>
                            </datatables:column>
                            <datatables:column title="BirthDate" cssStyle="width: 300px;" display="html">
                                <joda:format value="${cat.birthDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                            </datatables:column>
                            <datatables:column title="Type" cssStyle="width: 200px;" display="html">
                                <c:out value="${cat.type.name}"/>
                            </datatables:column>
                        </datatables:table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${pageContext.request.requestURI.endsWith('dogs')}">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=2>            
                    <p>Dogs</p>
                        <datatables:table id="dogs" data="${sel_owner.dogs}" cdn="true" row="dog" theme="bootstrap2" 
                                  cssClass="table table-striped" paginate="false" info="false"  filter="false"
                                  cssStyle="width: 350px;" align="left" >
                            <datatables:column title="Name" cssStyle="width: 200px;" display="html">
                                <c:out value="${dog.name}"/>
                            </datatables:column>
                            <datatables:column title="BirthDate" cssStyle="width: 300px;" display="html">
                                <joda:format value="${dog.birthDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                            </datatables:column>
                            <datatables:column title="Type" cssStyle="width: 200px;" display="html">
                                <c:out value="${dog.type.name}"/>
                            </datatables:column>
                            </datatables:table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </c:if>
            </table>

        </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can not call Java functions from JSTL as you are doing try using this [functions taglib](http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions)

Also have a look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_endswith.htm